# ¿Por qué cuando llamo a esta función modifica las dos listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
arregloPuntos = [[[6.596, 7.425, -9.098],
                  [8.074, -5.09, -6.243],
                  [-4.082, 4.1, -3.886],
                  [7.108, -9.654, -2.89]
                 ],  
                 [[5.915, -1.079, 1.285],
                  [0.35, -7.855, -7.896],
                  [-5.682, -1.054, 9.372],
                  [-4.765, -8.265, -9.312]
                 ]
                ]


def determinanteT(arreglo):
    for x in arreglo:
        x.append(1)

arregloPuntos2 = arregloPuntos
print("\nArreglo1: ", arregloPuntos)
print("\nArreglo2: ", arregloPuntos2)
for esfera in arregloPuntos:
    T = determinanteT(esfera)

print("\nArreglo1: ", arregloPuntos)
print("\nArreglo2: ", arregloPuntos2)
```

El problema es que, a pesar de hacer  `arregloPuntos2 = arreglo`, me encuentro con que ambas listas son modificas al pasar por la función:

> ```
> Arreglo1:  [[[6.596, 7.425, -9.098], [8.074, -5.09, -6.243],
>              [-4.082, 4.1, -3.886], [7.108, -9.654, -2.89]],
>             [[5.915, -1.079, 1.285], [0.35, -7.855, -7.896],
>              [-5.682, -1.054, 9.372], [-4.765, -8.265, -9.312]]
>             ]
>
> Arreglo2:  [[[6.596, 7.425, -9.098], [8.074, -5.09, -6.243],
>              [-4.082, 4.1, -3.886], [7.108, -9.654, -2.89]],
>             [[5.915, -1.079, 1.285], [0.35, -7.855, -7.896],
>              [-5.682, -1.054, 9.372], [-4.765, -8.265, -9.312]]
>             ]
>
> Arreglo1:  [[[6.596, 7.425, -9.098, 1], [8.074, -5.09, -6.243, 1],
>              [-4.082, 4.1, -3.886, 1], [7.108, -9.654, -2.89, 1]],
>             [[5.915, -1.079, 1.285, 1], [0.35, -7.855, -7.896, 1],
>              [-5.682, -1.054, 9.372, 1], [-4.765, -8.265, -9.312, 1]]
>              ]
>
> Arreglo2:  [[[6.596, 7.425, -9.098, 1], [8.074, -5.09, -6.243, 1],
>              [-4.082, 4.1, -3.886, 1], [7.108, -9.654, -2.89, 1]],
>             [[5.915, -1.079, 1.285, 1], [0.35, -7.855, -7.896, 1],
>              [-5.682, -1.054, 9.372, 1], [-4.765, -8.265, -9.312, 1]]
>             ]
> ```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Por qué si a la función le pasa las listas que contiene `arregloPuntos` también se agrega el 1 en las de `arregloPuntos2`?

Comment: Porque los arreglos son pasados por referencia.

Comment: En Python la asignación se hace por objeto. Al hacer `arregloPuntos2 = arregloPuntos` estás haciendo que `arregloPuntos2` apunte a la misma "dirección de memoria" que `arregloPuntos`, o que ambos nombres hagan referencia a la misma caja donde se almacena el valor. Al ser las listas objetos mutables, se puede apreciar la modificación en los elementos de ambas.

Answer (score 2):

En Python todo son objetos, desde un entero hasta una función. Una variable podemos considerarla simplemente como un **identificador o nombre que está asociado a una referencia a un objeto en memoria**, cuando haces:

```
arregloPuntos2 = arregloPuntos
```

lo único que haces es crear la variable `arregloPuntos2` y asignarle una nueva referencia al objeto al que apunta `arregloPuntos`. Por lo tanto, ambas variables están asociadas al mismo objeto en memoria, no es que modificar uno modifique el otro, es que son el mismo, son "dos nombres para el mismo objeto", dos caminos para llegar (referenciar) a la misma lista:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2]]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
2236248254872    
>>> id(b)
2236248254872   # Misma id == mismo objeto
>>> a[0][0]=5
>>> a
[[5, 2]]
>>> b
[[5, 2]]
```

Si quieres una copia real de tu lista debes usar `copy.deepcopy`:

```
import copy


arregloPuntos2 = copy.deepcopy(arregloPuntos)
```

`deepcopy` recorre recursivamente el objeto copiando también todos los objetos que encuentre en él (copia en profundidad).

```
>>> import copy

>>> a = [[1, 2]]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> id(a)
2236241700872
>>> id(b)
2236241880840
>>> id(a[0])
2236241820168
>>> id(b[0])
2236241842120
```

Si aplicas `copy.copy`, `list.copy` o `list[::]` realizas lo que se conoce como *shallow copy* o copia superficial, solo se copia el objeto al que apunta la variable, no las listas anidadas (u otros objetos) de su interior por lo que tendrías el mismo problema:

```
>>> import copy

>>> a = [[1, 2]]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)  # Similar a b = a[::] y b = a.copy()
>>> id(a)
2236240818312
>>> id(b)
2236241700680  
>>> id(a[0])
2236241842120
>>> id(b[0])
2236241842120
```

Python nunca pasa parámetros o asigna "por valor", en realidad tampoco lo hace "por referencia", el termino apropiado sería "paso por referencia a objeto". Estas confusiones se deben posiblemente a dos aspectos:

- Hay que tener en cuenta la diferencia que existe entre objetos mutables e inmutables, un objeto inmutable una vez creado no puede ser modificado, aunque lo parezca (por ejemplo al usar operadores como `+=`, `-=`, etc) siempre se produce una asignación y la creación de un nuevo objeto:

  ```
  >>> a = "Hola"
  >>> b = a
  >>> id(a)
  2236242016888
  >>> id(b)
  2236242016888

  >>> b += " Stack Overflow"
  >>> a
  'Hola'
  >>> b
  'Hola  Stack Overflow'
  >>> id(a)
  2236242016888
  >>> id(b)
  2236248254984

  >>> a = [1]
  >>> id(a)
  2236241880904
  >>> a += [5]
  >>> a
  [1, 5]
  >>> id(a)
  2236241880904
  ```

  Son objetos mutables `list`, `dict` y set. Son inmutables `int`, `float`, `str`, `bool`, `tuple`, y `frozenset`.
- Los ámbitos de las variables en las funciones, en Python a no ser que lo indiquemos mediante `global`, la creación de una variable o la reasignación a una que ya existiera globalmente  implica la creación de una variable local a la función, dejando la variable global del mismo nombre intacta.

  ```
  >>> def foo(a):
      print("Id del objeto antes de la adignación: ", id(a))
      a += " Stack Overflow" # Crea variable local a foo
      print(a)
      print("Id del objeto después de la adignación: ", id(a))


  >>> str_a = "Hola"
  >>> foo(str_a)
  Id del objeto antes de la adignación:  2236248254872
  Hola Stack Overflow
  Id del objeto después de la adignación:  2236248267416
  >>> str_a
  'Hola'
  >>> id(a)
  2236241880904
  ```

  Esto pasa porque se ha producido una asignación, no porque una lista y una cadena o entero se pasen de forma distinta:

  ```
  >>> def foo(a):
      print("Id del objeto antes de la adignación: ", id(a))
      a = [9] # Asignacion 
      print(a)
      print("Id del objeto después de la adignación: ", id(a))


      >>> list_a  = [1]
      >>> foo(list_a)
      Id del objeto antes de la adignación:  2236241879496
      [9]
      Id del objeto después de la adignación:  2236241820168
      >>> list_a
      [1]
  ```

  Ahora bien, si en vez de reasignar modificamos un objeto mutable, por ejemplo una lista mediante sus métodos `append`, `extend`, con `+=`, etc como a la función siempre le llega la referencia del objeto, esta modificación si se refleja en la variable global:

  ```
  >>> def foo(a):
      print("Id del objeto antes de modificarlo: ", id(a))
      a.append(9) 
      print(a)
      print("Id del objeto después de modificarlo: ", id(a))


  >>> list_a  = [1]
  >>> foo(list_a)
  Id del objeto antes de modificarlo:  2236248295176
  [1, 9]
  Id del objeto después de modificarlo:  2236248295176
  >>> list_a
  [1, 9]
  ```

  Es decir, la función lo que recibe es una referencia al objeto siempre, por lo que puedes acceder a sus atributos y métodos sin problemas y modificarlo si es mutable. Si es inmutable simplemente no se puede modificar y para alterarlo necesitamos crear un nuevo objeto, que de no asociarse a una variable global será local a la función y se destruirá cuando esta retorne.

  Por esta razón hay que tener cuidado cuando se modifica un objeto mutable en una función que lo recibe como parámetro, en cambio la "modificación" de un objeto inmutable siempre provoca la creación de una variable local.

Answer (score 1):

No soy un experto en python ni nada parecido pero creo que es así como funcionan los objetos:

Tu problema se debe a que la asignación se hace por objeto. Cuando realizas `objeto2 = objeto1` estas haciendo que el `objeto2` haga referencia al mismo espacio en la memoria al cual se refiere el `objeto1`.

Como ilustración, imagina que tu lista tiene forma de una caja, y que esta caja tiene dos etiquetas: "pertenece a `objeto1`" y "pertenece a `objeto2`". Ambas variables hacen referencia a la misma caja (lista). Por lo tanto, si modificas la lista, alteraras el valor de ambas variables (porque son referencias).