# Python diccionario no respeta keys

Tags: python

Mi programa itera sobre un conjunto de datos y extrae información para agregar valores a un diccionario:

```
for i in data:
    try: 
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['ENERO']+=int(i['ENERO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['FEBRERO']+=int(i['FEBRERO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['MARZO']+=int(i['MARZO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['ABRIL']+=int(i['ABRIL'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['MAYO']+=int(i['MAYO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['JUNIO']+=int(i['JUNIO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['JULIO']+=int(i['JULIO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['AGOSTO']+=int(i['AGOSTO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['SEPTIEMBRE']+=int(i['SEPTIEMBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['OCTUBRE']+=int(i['OCTUBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['NOVIEMBRE']+=int(i['NOVIEMBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['DICIEMBRE']+=int(i['DICIEMBRE'])
    except: pass
```

Esto debería darme la suma de valores separados por entidad, dentro de ellos separarlos por año y cada año tener un registro por mes, sin embargo suma los valores de cualquier entidad de cualquier año solo respetando los meses

```
{'AGUASCALIENTES': {'1997': {'ABRIL': 2713186,
                         'AGOSTO': 2779202,
                         'DICIEMBRE': 2548606,
                         'ENERO': 2596006,
                         'FEBRERO': 2583664,
                         'JULIO': 2729596,
                         'JUNIO': 2796138,
                         'MARZO': 2834610,
                         'MAYO': 2850637,
                         'NOVIEMBRE': 2656333,
                         'OCTUBRE': 2852315,
                         'SEPTIEMBRE': 2744739},
                '1998': {'ABRIL': 2713186,
                         'AGOSTO': 2779202,
                         'DICIEMBRE': 2548606,
                         'ENERO': 2596006,
                         'FEBRERO': 2583664,
                         'JULIO': 2729596,
                         'JUNIO': 2796138,
                         'MARZO': 2834610,
                         'MAYO': 2850637,
                         'NOVIEMBRE': 2656333,
                         'OCTUBRE': 2852315,
                         'SEPTIEMBRE': 2744739},
                 ....
                'Estado': 'AGUASCALIENTES'},
 'BAJA CALIFORNIA': {'1997': {'ABRIL': 2713186,
                              'AGOSTO': 2779202,
                              'DICIEMBRE': 2548606,
                              'ENERO': 2596006,
                              'FEBRERO': 2583664,
                              'JULIO': 2729596,
                              'JUNIO': 2796138,
                              'MARZO': 2834610,
                              'MAYO': 2850637,
                              'NOVIEMBRE': 2656333,
                              'OCTUBRE': 2852315,
                              'SEPTIEMBRE': 2744739},
                     '1998': {'ABRIL': 2713186,
                              'AGOSTO': 2779202,
                              'DICIEMBRE': 2548606,
                              'ENERO': 2596006,
                              'FEBRERO': 2583664,
                              'JULIO': 2729596,
                              'JUNIO': 2796138,
                              'MARZO': 2834610,
                              'MAYO': 2850637,
                              'NOVIEMBRE': 2656333,
                              'OCTUBRE': 2852315,
                              'SEPTIEMBRE': 2744739},
                     ......
                     'Estado': 'BAJA CALIFORNIA'}
```

Como se puede ver todos los años y en este caso aunque solo publico 2 estados se repite para todos en el diccionario, si alguien tiene alguna posible solución estaré muy agradecido.
El código completo es el siguiente:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient as mongo
from pprint import pprint
db=mongo('localhost',27017).pruebas
data=db.delitosb.aggregate([{
    '$project':{
        '_id':0,
        'AÑO':1,
        'INEGI':1,
        'ENTIDAD':1,
        'DELITO':1,
        'MODALIDAD':1,
        'ENERO':1,
        'FEBRERO':1,
        'MARZO':1,
        'ABRIL':1,
        'MAYO':1,
        'JUNIO':1,
        'JULIO':1,
        'AGOSTO':1,
        'SEPTIEMBRE':1,
        'OCTUBRE':1,
        'NOVIEMBRE':1,
        'DICIEMBRE':1,
    }
    }])
meses={
        'ENERO':0,
        'FEBRERO':0,
        'MARZO':0,
        'ABRIL':0,
        'MAYO':0,
        'JUNIO':0,
        'JULIO':0,
        'AGOSTO':0,
        'SEPTIEMBRE':0,
        'OCTUBRE':0,
        'NOVIEMBRE':0,
        'DICIEMBRE':0
        }
formato={
        "AGUASCALIENTES":{"Estado":"AGUASCALIENTES"},
        "BAJA CALIFORNIA":{"Estado":"BAJA CALIFORNIA"},
        "BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR":{"Estado":"BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR"},
        "CAMPECHE":{"Estado":"CAMPECHE"},
        "CHIAPAS":{"Estado":"CHIAPAS"},
        "CHIHUAHUA":{"Estado":"CHIHUAHUA"},
        "COAHUILA":{"Estado":"COAHUILA"},
        "COLIMA":{"Estado":"COLIMA"},
        "CIUDAD DE MEXICO":{"Estado":"CIUDAD DE MEXICO"},
        "DURANGO":{"Estado":"DURANGO"},
        "GUANAJUATO":{"Estado":"GUANAJUATO"},
        "GUERRERO":{"Estado":"GUERRERO"},
        "HIDALGO":{"Estado":"HIDALGO"},
        "JALISCO":{"Estado":"JALISCO"},
        "MEXICO":{"Estado":"MEXICO"},
        "MICHOACAN":{"Estado":"MICHOACAN"},
        "MORELOS":{"Estado":"MORELOS"},
        "NAYARIT":{"Estado":"NAYARIT"},
        "NUEVO LEON":{"Estado":"NUEVO LEON"},
        "OAXACA":{"Estado":"OAXACA"},
        "PUEBLA":{"Estado":"PUEBLA"},
        "QUERETARO":{"Estado":"QUERETARO"},
        "QUINTANA ROO":{"Estado":"QUINTANA ROO"},
        "SAN LUIS POTOSI":{"Estado":"SAN LUIS POTOSI"},
        "SINALOA":{"Estado":"SINALOA"},
        "SONORA":{"Estado":"SONORA"},
        "TABASCO":{"Estado":"TABASCO"},
        "TAMAULIPAS":{"Estado":"TAMAULIPAS"},
        "TLAXCALA":{"Estado":"TLAXCALA"},
        "VERACRUZ":{"Estado":"VERACRUZ"},
        "YUCATAN":{"Estado":"YUCATAN"},
        "ZACATECAS":{"Estado":"ZACATECAS"}}
años=[
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1999",
    "2000",
    "2001",
    "2002",
    "2003",
    "2004",
    "2005",
    "2006",
    "2007",
    "2008",
    "2009",
    "2010",
    "2011",
    "2012",
    "2013",
    "2014",
    "2015",
    "2016",
    "2017"
    ]
for i in formato:
    for j in años:
        formato[i][j]=meses
count=0
for i in data:
    try: 
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['ENERO']+=int(i['ENERO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['FEBRERO']+=int(i['FEBRERO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['MARZO']+=int(i['MARZO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['ABRIL']+=int(i['ABRIL'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['MAYO']+=int(i['MAYO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['JUNIO']+=int(i['JUNIO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['JULIO']+=int(i['JULIO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['AGOSTO']+=int(i['AGOSTO'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['SEPTIEMBRE']+=int(i['SEPTIEMBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['OCTUBRE']+=int(i['OCTUBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['NOVIEMBRE']+=int(i['NOVIEMBRE'])
        formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']]['DICIEMBRE']+=int(i['DICIEMBRE'])
    except: 
        pass
pprint(formato)
#for estado in formato:
#   db.formato.insert_one(formato[estado])
```

Los registros son como:

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d373297076557ea93e296f9"),
    "AÑO" : "1997",
    "INEGI" : "1",
    "ENTIDAD" : "AGUASCALIENTES",
    "MODALIDAD" : "DELITOS PATRIMONIALES",
    "TIPO" : "ABUSO DE CONFIANZA",
    "SUBTIPO" : "ABUSO DE CONFIANZA",
    "ENERO" : "17",
    "FEBRERO" : "17",
    "MARZO" : "17",
    "ABRIL" : "17",
    "MAYO" : "17",
    "JUNIO" : "17",
    "JULIO" : "32",
    "AGOSTO" : "0",
    "SEPTIEMBRE" : "38",
    "OCTUBRE" : "28",
    "NOVIEMBRE" : "22",
    "DICIEMBRE" : "31"
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo creas los diccionarios de los meses del diccionario  `formato`?. Es bastante probable que el problema sea que todos son el mismo objeto en realidad. Algo similar a esto --> [Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105431/15089) <--.

Comment: Por otro lado, si facilitas una muestra de `data`, harás mucho más fácil la reproducción del código y por tanto facilitarte una respuesta.

Comment: Adrián no agregues el código en comentarios, usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282105/python-diccionario-no-respeta-keys?noredirect=1#comment518724_282105) que hay debajo de la pregunta y agregalo a la misma. Los comentarios no es sitio para ello, además tienen un numero limitado de caracteres y no respetan identacion ni formato alguno del código.

Comment: @Adrian, podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

El problema en esencia es el mismo que el presentado en estas preguntas, solo que en este caso eran listas:

- [Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105431/15089)
- [¿Por qué cuando llamo a esta función modifica las dos listas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/176887/15089)

El error está en:

```
meses={
        'ENERO':0,
        'FEBRERO':0,
        'MARZO':0,
        'ABRIL':0,
        'MAYO':0,
        'JUNIO':0,
        'JULIO':0,
        'AGOSTO':0,
        'SEPTIEMBRE':0,
        'OCTUBRE':0,
        'NOVIEMBRE':0,
        'DICIEMBRE':0
        }

for i in formato:
    for j in años:
        formato[i][j] = meses  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

En Python una variable no es más que un nombre asociado una referencia a un objeto en memoria. Cuando  `a = b`, lo que estás haciendo es simplemente asignar a la variable `b` una referencia al **mismo objeto** en memoria al que está asociada `a`.

> ```
> >>> a = {"k": 7}
> >>> b = a
> >>> id(a)
> 140664248700360
> >>> id(b)
> 140664248700360
> >>> a is b
> True
> >>> a["k"] = 13
> >>> a
> {'k': 13}
> >>> b
> {'k': 13}
>
> >>> a = {"k": 7}
> >>> b = a.copy()
> >>> id(a)
> 140664248697336
> >>> id(b)
> 140664244673571
> >>> a is b
> False
> >>> a["k"] = 13
> >>> a
> {'k': 13}
> >>> b
> {'k': 7}
> ```

Cuando haces `formato[i][j] = meses` estás **asignando el mismo diccionario a todos los años de todas las entidades**. Como un diccionario es un objeto mutable, cuando modificas el diccionario asignado a `formato["AGUASCALIENTES"]["1998"]` por ejemplo el cambio afecta a "todos los demás" porque son el mismo objeto en realidad.

La solución es simple, asignar un objeto distinto a cada calve año:

```
for i in formato:
    for j in años:
        formato[i][j] =meses.copy()
```

Si el diccionario tuviera como valores objetos mutables, sería necesario usar una copia en profundidad mediante `copy.deepcopy()`.

---

Otra posibilidad es no generar el diccionario con toda las claves desde el inicio, sino ir generándolo de forma dinámica en función de los datos. Esto es especialmente útil cuando no conoces de antemano el rango de los dato, por ejemplo si desconocemos los años o las entidades en tu ejemplo de antemano. Hay varias formas:

- Usando `collections.defaultdict`:

  ```
  from collections import defaultdict
  from functools import partial



  MESES = ('ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO',
           'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE')

  formato = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, partial(dict.fromkeys, MESES, 0)))
  for i in data:
      for mes in MESES:
          try:
              formato[i['ENTIDAD']][i['AÑO']][mes] += int(i[mes])
          except (KeyError, ValueError):
              pass

  pprint(formato)
  ```

  En vez de usar diccionarios estándar se usa `collections.defaultdict`, pero es una subclase de `dict` que se puede usar como un diccionario normal sin problemas o lo podemos convertir en uno con solo hacer `dict(mi_defaultdict)`.
- Usar diccionarios estándar y `dict.setdefault()`:

  ```
  MESES = ('ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO',
           'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE')

  formato = {}
  for i in data:
      for mes in MESES:
          try:
              (formato.setdefault(i['ENTIDAD'], {})
                      .setdefault(i['AÑO'], {m: 0 for m in MESES})
               )[mes] += int(i[mes])
          except (KeyError, ValueError):
              pass

  pprint(formato)
  ```

  En este caso se usan diccionarios estándar, pero es menos eficiente que el uso de `DefaultDict`.