# Ordenar lista de menor a mayor, list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

estoy teniendo un problema:

> list index out of range

a la hora de ordenar mi lista. Si no se entiende puedo ser más especifico

```
lista_num_principal = [[2,4,12],[3,3,3],[1,1,1]]
lista_valores = [18,9,3]

lista_auxiliar_principal = lista_num_principal

if (opcion == 1):
#Hay varias opciones para realizar, esta seria la 1

    i = len(lista_auxiliar_principal) #aqui me da error: "list index out of range

    while (i >= 0):

        lista_numeros_actual = lista_auxiliar_principal[i]                                                           
        #representa una serie de numeros en la lista principal
        valor_actual = lista_valores[i]                                                                              
        #representa el valor que suma esa serie de numeros

        while ((valor_actual <= lista_valores[i]) and (i >= 0)):                                                     
        #busco la posicion a donde insertar el elemento correctamente
            i = i - 1

        posicion = i

        if (valor_actual == lista_valores[posicion]):
            lista_auxiliar_principal[posicion] = lista_numeros_actual
        else:
            for j in range(0, posicion):
                lista_auxiliar_principal[j] = lista_auxiliar_principal[j+1]
            lista_auxiliar_principal[posicion] = lista_numeros_actual

        i = len(lista_auxiliar_principal)

    print('De menor a mayor, la lista principal quedaría conformada de la siguiente manera: ',lista_auxiliar_principal)
```

Comment: Hola Dementira, te damos la bienvenida a [es.so]. La respuesta de @JorgeLuis es correcta, solo dos observaciones: Primero,  supongo que se trata de alguna tarea académica que te obliga a desarrollar el algoritmo, lo digo porque en situaciones normales Python permite hacer esto de forma mucho más eficiente con solo `lista_auxiliar_principal = sorted(lista_num_principal, key=sum, reverse=True)`.

Comment: Segundo, ten mucho cuidado con `lista_auxiliar_principal = lista_num_principal`, no hace lo que creo que piensas (crear una copia de  `lista_num_principal`). Esto solo hace que `lista_auxiliar_principal` quede asociada a la misma referencia que `lista_num_principal`. Ambas variables apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria, son dos nombres para la misma cosa, (que es además mutable, una lista), cuando modificas `lista_auxiliar_principal` también lo haces en `lista_num_principal`, si te fijas  también queda ordenada al final.... Puedes mirarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/176905/15089. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta, no es un ejercicio académico, simplemente estoy aprendiendo Python en casa.
Vi que existen módulos predefinidos para poder hacer éste tipo de cosas, pero quería hacer el algoritmo para aprender.
Lo que no sabía es que lista_auxiliar_principal y lista_num_principal apuntaban a la misma posición en memoria. Es un buen dato, porque yo quiero mantener lista_num_principal intacta. Asique ahora se algo más que debo hallar la manera de resolver. Yo quiero que lista_auxiliar_principal sea una copia por valor de lista_num_principal y no la modifique.

Comment: En mi respuesta enlazada en mi comentario anterior tienes varias posibilidades, si quieres que cualquier modificación de la lista auxiliar no modifique la original necesitas una copia en profundidad (en una copia superficial (shallowcopy) la lista se copia pero las sublistas siguen siendo los mismos objetos). O usas `copy.deepcopy` o iteras sobre la lista y realizas la copia manualmente, algo así: `lista_auxiliar_principal = [sublista[::] for sublista in lista_num_principal]`. Los enteros no necesitas copiarlos porque son objetos inmutables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces

```
  i = len(lista_auxiliar_principal)
```

te regresa 3 pero los arreglos empiezan en 0, osea tu arreglo solo tiene las posiciones 0, 1, 2 y tu estas tratando de poner la 3

Ejecute tu programa y el error me sale en esta linea

```
lista_numeros_actual = lista_auxiliar_principal[i]
```

y al inicio i es 3 osea lista_auxiliar_principal[3] cuando solo tiene las posiciones del 0 al 2

Para arreglarlo puedes hacer

```
i = len(lista_auxiliar_principal) -1
```

pero estoy viendo que al final del while pones

```
i = len(lista_auxiliar_principal)
```

osea estas haciendo un while infinito, nunca va a terminar

Comment: Gracias por sus observaciones, me van a ayudar mucho.

Comment: De nada, Saludos